# Python flask gunicorn nginx uploading files

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I deployed a flask web app on a digitalocean server following this tutorial: [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04)

I can access the templates load pages correctly. However, I cannot upload or receive files. I followed this tutorial to upload files: [link](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/fileuploads/)

It seems like there's an issue with nginx.
Here's what it looks like right now:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server_domain_or_IP;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/project/project.sock;
    }
}
```

nginx error.log:

```
2016/05/04 23:08:31 [crit] 2041#0: *16 rename() "/var/lib/nginx/proxy/0/01/0000000010" to 
"/usr/share/nginx/html/login" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream, client: 
[ip], server: [ip], request: "GET /login HTTP/1.1",
upstream: "http://unix:/home/user/project/project.sock:/login", host: "[ip]"
```

Update: I've updated my project's nginx conf file and now I can serve images to user, but I still can't upload:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server_domain_or_IP;
    client_max_body_size 500M;
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/project/project.sock;
        location /photo/ {
            proxy_store on;
            proxy_store_access all:rw;
            #photo directory
            alias /home/user/project/project/photos/;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some more info would be helpful, any error messages in the app logs or nginx logs? What's your nginx config look like?

Comment: I've edited the question with the nginx code. I'm not sure how to view the error logs.

Comment: The logs should be at `/var/log/nginx/`

Comment: alright, i've added the error.log

Answer (score 0):

I make upload files normally to the flask using Nginx as a proxy.
The difference in relation to what you are trying to do ...
I didn't turn the flask project into a Linux service.
I use PM2 to keep the flask running in the background even when the user logs off.

A tip is to leave the flask running in a terminal without PM2 to be able to watch the outputs while trying to send a file. It will show what type of error is occurring.

This working in POP-OS 20.04 LTS...

Another detail is to check if the Flask user is allowed to write on the spot.

My Nginx configuration is as follows:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000$request_uri;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    client_max_body_size 5M;
    }
        location /upload {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000$request_uri;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_store on;
        proxy_store_access all:rw;
        client_max_body_size 5M;
        }
```